How to find the mean number of consecutive days using dates in R?
I am working with climate data that I have added dates to and subsetted down to just including the data that has the temperature above the 90th percentile for 3 or more days.
set.seed(12368)
A <- data.frame("Y" = rep(1990:2009, each = 360), "M" = rep(1:12, each = 30, times = 20), "D" = rep(1:30, 240), "Temp" = c(sample(0:35, size = 7200, replace = TRUE)))
B <- data.frame("Y" = rep(1990:2009, each = 360), "M" = rep(1:12, each = 30, times = 20), "D" = rep(1:30, 240), "Temp" = c(sample(-10:22, size = 7200, replace = TRUE)))
C <- data.frame("Y" = rep(1990:2009, each = 360), "M" = rep(1:12, each = 30, times = 20), "D" = rep(1:30, 240), "Temp" = c(sample(3:42, size = 7200, replace = TRUE)))

climate <- list("Alist" = A, "Blist" = B, "Clist" = C)

#climate

library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
datedclimate <- lapply(lapply(climate, 
                               function(x) 
                                 x %<>% 
                                 mutate("Date" = as.Date(with(x, paste(Y,M,D, sep="-")),"%Y-%m-%d"))
),
function(y)
  y %>% relocate("Date")
)
datedclimate

tm <- lapply(datedclimate, \(x) {
  y <- as.data.frame(subset(x,
                            Temp > quantile(Temp, probs = 0.90, na.rm = TRUE)) 
  ) 
  
  y[unique(
    sort(
      unlist(
        lapply( # this iterates through all of my data sets
          which(
            c(diff(y[,'Date'])==1, FALSE) & c(diff(y[,'Date'], diff=2)==0, FALSE, FALSE)),
          \(x) x + 0:2) 
      ))),]
}
)
tm

The next step I am looking to do is then find the average number of days for each consecutive amount of days. For example, the subsetted C list has 5 stretches of 3 consecutive days and 1 stretch of 4 consecutive days. Therefore, the average number of consecutive days would be 3.17 from (3+3+3+3+3+4)/6.
I tried to modify the code from this question, but it does not return the right numbers. I would also prefer to modify/work with the subsetted data, tm, from above if possible.
ConsecMean <- function(x) { 
  x <- ifelse(x > quantile(x, probs = 0.90, na.rm = TRUE), 0, 1) 
  cs <- cumsum(x) 
  cs <- cs[x == 0] 
  mean <- mean(table(cs)) 
  return(mean) 
}

tri <- lapply(lapply(datedclimate, "[[", 5), ConsecMean)
tri

> tri
$Alist
[1] 1.105735

$Blist
[1] 1.104746

$Clist
[1] 1.099693

So, I'm looking for a function that I can apply to the list of data frames (climate) that will return this average number for each data frame in the list. I'm thinking I should use lapply, but I don't know where to go from there. I also tried to use rle, but it is not compatible with the Date format and I also think that rle is not the right function to use for this lol. What code/functions would you recommend using to solve this problem?

Aside: the last two lines (mean <- mean(table(cs)), return(mean)) are a lot of syntactic noise and clutter for mean(table(cs)) (no need for the temporary variable, nor for return()). Keeping unnecessary noise out of the code makes it easier to read and maintain and drastically reduces the occurrence of bugs.

The answer is always   : Use  rle  .  The rest is just data rearrangement :-)

Using tm in the Note at the end seqid assigns a unique id which is the same for all Dates in any particular consecutive sequence of dates, table counts the elements in each such group giving a vector of counts and mean takes their average.
library(collapse)

sapply(tm, function(x) mean(table(seqid(x$Date))))
##    Alist    Blist    Clist 
## 3.000000 3.000000 3.166667 

Note
tm <- list(Alist = structure(list(Date = structure(c(9344, 9345, 9346, 
10998, 10999, 11000, 11007, 11008, 11009, 11428, 11429, 11430, 
11952, 11953, 11954, 13415, 13416, 13417), class = "Date"), Y = c(1995L, 
1995L, 1995L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L, 2006L, 2006L, 2006L), M = c(8L, 
8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L), D = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 26L), Temp = c(33L, 34L, 33L, 34L, 
33L, 33L, 34L, 33L, 35L, 34L, 33L, 33L, 35L, 35L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
35L)), row.names = c(2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 3641L, 3642L, 3643L, 
3650L, 3651L, 3652L, 4066L, 4067L, 4068L, 4582L, 4583L, 4584L, 
6024L, 6025L, 6026L), class = "data.frame"), Blist = structure(list(
    Date = structure(c(8041, 8042, 8043, 9820, 9821, 9822, 10759, 
    10760, 10761, 12383, 12384, 12385, 13116, 13117, 13118), class = "Date"), 
    Y = c(1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1999L, 1999L, 
    1999L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L), M = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    12L), D = c(7L, 8L, 9L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 27L, 
    28L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 1L), Temp = c(20L, 20L, 22L, 22L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L)), row.names = c(727L, 
728L, 729L, 2480L, 2481L, 2482L, 3407L, 3408L, 3409L, 5007L, 
5008L, 5009L, 5729L, 5730L, 5731L), class = "data.frame"), Clist = structure(list(
    Date = structure(c(7504, 7505, 7506, 7616, 7617, 7618, 10090, 
    10091, 10092, 10635, 10636, 10637, 10700, 10701, 10702, 13591, 
    13592, 13593, 13594), class = "Date"), Y = c(1990L, 1990L, 
    1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1997L, 1997L, 1997L, 1999L, 1999L, 
    1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 1999L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L, 2007L), 
    M = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), D = c(19L, 20L, 21L, 8L, 9L, 
    10L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 19L, 20L, 
    21L, 22L), Temp = c(39L, 39L, 40L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 39L, 39L, 
    42L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 40L, 40L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 40L, 41L)), row.names = c(199L, 
200L, 201L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 2747L, 2748L, 2749L, 3283L, 3284L, 
3285L, 3349L, 3350L, 3351L, 6199L, 6200L, 6201L, 6202L), class = "data.frame"))


I think you're on the right track with rle(), but need to use a different version of it. If you're willing to consider a tibble-based approach that makes use of by-group processing, then I believe my code below will do what you want. However, I'm not certain of this because the data-generating code that you provided doesn't match up with your description of what should be in Alist when I run it on my machine (R 4.4.1, Win 10).
You stated:

the subsetted A list has 4 stretches of 3 consecutive days and 1 stretch of 6 consecutive days. Therefore, the average number of consecutive days would be 3.6 from (3+3+3+3+6)/5.

However, when I run your code I get six runs of three consecutive days; see the following (annotated) data from tm$Alist:
> tm$Alist
           Date    Y M  D Temp
2012 1995-08-02 1995 8  2   33     # start 1
2013 1995-08-03 1995 8  3   34
2014 1995-08-04 1995 8  4   33     # end 1
3641 2000-02-11 2000 2 11   34     # start 2
3642 2000-02-12 2000 2 12   33
3643 2000-02-13 2000 2 13   33     # end 2
3650 2000-02-20 2000 2 20   34     # start 3
3651 2000-02-21 2000 2 21   33
3652 2000-02-22 2000 2 22   35     # end 3
4066 2001-04-16 2001 4 16   34     # start 4
4067 2001-04-17 2001 4 17   33
4068 2001-04-18 2001 4 18   33     # end 4
4582 2002-09-22 2002 9 22   35     # start 5
4583 2002-09-23 2002 9 23   35
4584 2002-09-24 2002 9 24   33     # end 5
6024 2006-09-24 2006 9 24   34     # start 6
6025 2006-09-25 2006 9 25   35
6026 2006-09-26 2006 9 26   35     # end 6

Given the output I'm seeing, the correct average number of consecutive days would be exactly 3 for Alist. Unless you wanted to group by year and month, in which case runs #2 and 3 above would collapse into a single run of six days?
Regardless, here is the code that I came up with. Note that it uses the rleidv() function from the data.table package, but I'm fairly certain data.table is installed when you install the tidyverse package. In other words, I'm assuming you have it installed already.
set.seed(12368)
A <- data.frame("Y" = rep(1990:2009, each = 360), "M" = rep(1:12, each = 30, times = 20), "D" = rep(1:30, 240), "Temp" = c(sample(0:35, size = 7200, replace = TRUE)))
B <- data.frame("Y" = rep(1990:2009, each = 360), "M" = rep(1:12, each = 30, times = 20), "D" = rep(1:30, 240), "Temp" = c(sample(-10:22, size = 7200, replace = TRUE)))
C <- data.frame("Y" = rep(1990:2009, each = 360), "M" = rep(1:12, each = 30, times = 20), "D" = rep(1:30, 240), "Temp" = c(sample(3:42, size = 7200, replace = TRUE)))

library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(A, B, C, .id = "id") |>
  as_tibble() |>
  mutate("Date" = as.Date(paste(Y, M, D, sep = "-"), "%Y-%m-%d")) |>
  filter(is.na(Date) == FALSE) |>
  relocate(Date) |>
  arrange(id, Date) |>
  mutate(
    keepflag = Temp > quantile(Temp, probs = 0.90, na.rm = TRUE),
    runs = data.table::rleidv(keepflag),
    .by = id
  ) |>
  filter(keepflag == TRUE) |>
  count(id, runs) |>
  filter(n >= 3) |>
  summarize(ConsecMean = mean(n), .by = id)

In the code above:

bind_rows() "stacks" the data.frames, one on top of the other, and creates an additional variable named id to keep track of which data.frame each row in the output came from
as_tibble() converts the data.frame to a tibble for nicer printing
builds the Date variable from the Y, M, and D components
filter() drops records where the constructed date is NA, namely in February of each year
relocate() moves the Date variable to the first column of the tibble
arrange() sorts the tibble by source table first (id), then by Date in preparation of using by-group run-length encoding
the second mutate() processes the data by id column value (.by = id) to construct (1) a logical flag that identifies records that are above the 90th percentile for Temp and (2) the RLE identifier (using the data.table::rleidv() function) which assigns an integer (starting at 1) for each record, incrementing by 1 when a different value is encountered, effectively grouping the consecutive dates
filter(keepflag == TRUE) drops all records where Temp was not above the 90th percentile
count() counts the number of dates in each set of RLE IDs from each of the source data.frames and stores this value (by default) in a new variable named n
filter(n >= 3) drops runs that were not a least three consecutive days long, and
summarize() creates the ConsecMean variable by id column value

The result that I get for your data using this code is
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  id    ConsecMean
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 1           3   
2 2           3   
3 3           3.17


Hi yes you're right about the A list, I misread it by accident my bad

You might want to use parts of this approach. Notice that there is no need for external packages.
lapply(climate, \(l) {
  x = transform(l, Date = as.Date(paste(Y, M, D, sep = "-"), "%Y-%m-%d")) |>
    subset(select = c(Date, Temp), # cosmetics 
           subset = Temp > quantile(Temp, probs = .9, na.rm = TRUE)) |>
    sort_by(~Date) 
  i = cumsum(c(0L, diff(x$Date) != 1L))
  data.frame(start = x$Date[c(1L, diff(i)) == 1L], n = rle(i)$lengths) |>
    subset(n > 2L) |> with(mean(n))
})

giving
$Alist
[1] 3

$Blist
[1] 3

$Clist
[1] 3.166667

I wrapped parts of unnecessary data handling and some cosmetics inside the single lapply-call. You might want to use them elsewhere, probably separated, in your code.
If we remove the tricky |> with(mean(n)), convenient data frames containing the start dates are returned:
$Alist
         start n
142 1995-08-02 3
271 2000-02-11 3
272 2000-02-20 3
306 2001-04-16 3
354 2002-09-22 3
466 2006-09-24 3

$Blist
         start n
50  1992-01-07 3
204 1996-11-20 3
278 1999-06-17 3
413 2003-11-27 3
484 2005-11-29 3

$Clist
         start n
25  1990-07-19 3
33  1990-11-08 3
266 1997-08-17 3
320 1999-02-13 3
325 1999-04-19 3
555 2007-03-19 4

